# C# set breakpoint on paint event but cannot step through or past on debug?

Tags: c#, debugging, events, paint, step-into

I am really not sure if it is an issue with my inexperience with C#, VS 2010, debug, .net, or events in general, so please be bear with me. I have a project drawing an Alphabet Aquarium. Adding letters in different colors to a panel and then animate them. It is a simple windows form project that includes two classes, Fishtank and Fish.  A paint event is uses to draw the colored letters and it is our task to animate them. In order to understand how the paint event is using the classes with initial load and controls, I set a breakpoint. With the breakpoint, I cannot step through or over the paint event. Without the breakpoint, the program loads?? Is it an issue with my ineperience, the code, the debugging or what??

```
     private void fishTankPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop through each fish in our fish tank, and draw them.
        for (int i = 0; i < _fishTank.CountFish(); i++)
        {
            Fish fish = _fishTank.GetFish(i);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(fish.FishLetter, new Font("Arial", 10),
                new SolidBrush(fish.FishColor), new Point(fish.XPosition, fish.YPosition));
        }
        fishCountLabel.Text = _fishTank.CountFish().ToString();

    }

class Fish
{
    private Color _fishColor;
    public Color FishColor
    {
        get { return _fishColor; }
        set { _fishColor = value; }
    }

    private int _xPosition;
    public int XPosition
    {
        get { return _xPosition; }
        set { _xPosition = value; }
    }

    private int _yPosition;
    public int YPosition
    {
        get { return _yPosition; }
        set { _yPosition = value; }
    }

    private string _fishLetter;
    public string FishLetter
    {
        get { return _fishLetter; }
        set { _fishLetter = value; }
    }

    private string _direction;
    public string Direction
    {
        get { return _direction; }
        set { _direction = value; }
    }
    public Fish(string fishLetter, int xPosition, int yPosition, Color fishColor, string fishDirection)
    {
        // If no letter specified, use "X."
        if (fishLetter.Length == 0)
        fishLetter = "X";
        _fishLetter = fishLetter;

        // Ensure the position is >= 0.
        if (xPosition < 0)
        xPosition = 0;
        _xPosition = xPosition;

        if (yPosition < 0)
        yPosition = 0;
        _yPosition = yPosition;

        // Set the fish color.
        _fishColor = fishColor;

        // Set fish direction

    }
}class FishTank
{
    // Use a List collection to hold the fish.
    private List<Fish> _fishTank = new List<Fish>();
    public int CountFish()
    {
        return _fishTank.Count;
    }
    public Fish GetFish(int position)
    {
        return _fishTank[position];
    }
    public void AddFish(Fish fish)
    {
        _fishTank.Add(fish);
    }
    public void ClearFish()
    {
        _fishTank.Clear();
    }
}
```

Feedback would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you step "over" the paint event?  Are you saying that, if you put a breakpoint in your handler (`fishTankPanel_Paint`) it never gets hit?  Is your project building (is the little red dot on that line solid or empty)?

Comment: Please add more information. On which line do you set the breakpoint? Does the debugger freeze, does the breakpoint not hit, or what exactly happens?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!. I have placed the breakpoint on the paint event shown. Specifically on the for loop shown. I have also tried after the for loop, just to see if I can get out of the event. Stepping in runs through the loop, as expected runs the last statement of the event, briefly shows the form and then runs again the event. I am caught in the event or so it seems to me. From teh for loop I go to the Fishtank class, then back to the  loop. It is as if the _fishTank.Count makes the event hang?? Oh well. I am clueless why it does not work.

Comment: The project does build when breakpoint is not there, it is a solid breakpoint. Debugger does not freeze.

Comment: Being 'caught' in the event is a common problem if you don't have enough screen estate. What most likely happens in your case is that the debugger (or some other VisualStudio window) covers the debuggee's GUI (partially), so whenever the focus switches from the debugger to your program, it will trigger a Paint event. Make sure, that the Visual Studio window(s) and your program window do not touch. If the Paint event still happens, check your code for possible places where just the event of becoming the active window or receiving the keyboard focus might trigger the Paint event.

Comment: Alternatively, if you cannot resolve the problem in reasonable time, you might want to look into remote debugging. Either have a second PC where your program runs (undisturbed by the debugger GUI), or use a VM as host for the program to debug.

Comment: Your right, shifted the windows and now, am not caught in the event. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While single-step debugging a paint method, being 'caught' in a seemingly endless loop of paint events is a common problem if your software's window (that which is being debugged) is at least partially overlapping with one of Visual Studio's windows - an overlap of even one pixel might be enough to trigger this symptom.

What happens is that whenever you do a step in the debugger, the focus switches from the debugger window to your program. Since the program window, which was at least partially covered by one of the Visual Studio windows, is now brought to the foreground again, it will trigger a Paint event. Then the focus will switch back to the debugger, which again will (partially) cover the program window. Executing the next step, the whole procedure repeats, and you are confronted with a seemingly never-ending sequence of paint events.

To avoid this issue, make sure that the Visual Studio window(s) and your program window **do not touch**.

If the paint events still continue to happen although debugger and program windows are spatially separated, your code triggers paint event under other conditions as well. Examples of typical candidates which might trigger paint events would be handlers for events telling a window it has become the active window or handlers for focus events.

However, figuring this out might become somewhat cumbersome if the focus frequently switches between the debugger window and your program. If such a problem is suspected, the recommended approach would be to use remote debugging. Remote debugging means that the program to debug runs on a different machine/environment than the debugger, and thus is totally undisturbed from the debugger UI. For the debug environment you might use a second physical computer, but often using a virtual machine is a reasonable option as well.